# CloudFoundry+MySQL+Hibernate+hmb2ddl.auto=true redeployment issue

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, cloud-foundry

I developed a simple application and deployed on CloudFoundry.
I am using Spring 3.1, Mysql Service, JPA(Hibernate provider) with annotated Entities using hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update.

When I deployed for the first time it created the User table and works as expected.
But when I updated the application and redeployed on CloudFoundry I am getting the following error.
Any idea on how to resolve this?

```
SchemaUpdate - could not complete schema update
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'system_sequences' in information_schema
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:382)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3603)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3535)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2150)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2620)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2570)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1476)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.initSequences(DatabaseMetadata.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.<init>(DatabaseMetadata.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.<init>(DatabaseMetadata.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:373)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1842)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:902)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:257)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:400)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:275)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1443)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1079)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1002)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Comment: do **not** use SchemaUpdate in production. create the update script with Schemaupdate in development, review it, test it, and apply manually (e.g. through updateSchema() method)

Comment: found the answer..its my bad...i set the db dialect to HSQL in local environment and forgot to change to MySQL when deployed on CloudFoundry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the original poster (sivaprasadreddy.k) answered in a comment, changing the DB dialect to MySQL resolved the issue:

> i set the db dialect to HSQL in local environment and forgot to change to MySQL when deployed on CloudFoundry